# Is there any continuous distribution (except Gaussian) that can be characterized by their first and second moments only?

Tags: mathematical-physics, probability, statistics

I am trying to figure out why Gaussian distribution is uniquely significant in random physical processes. I think the answer lies in its characterization by only two moments. In a way it is the simplest continuous distribution (except Dirac delta which is again a limiting case of Gaussian).

Comment: There is no physics content in this question; it should probably be asked on [the stats site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are any number of _families_ of distributions characterized by two moments, e.g. [Beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) or [Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution). A similar but perhaps more impressive fact about characterizing Gaussians: they are precisely the real distributions with all [cumulants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant) defined and finite and only finitely many of them nonzero.

Comment: Thanks J.G. That helped. Sorry Mike, but the reason I asked it here is because I wanted a physicist's perspective. I'm sorry it violates the rules, the question is closed anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that normal distributions show up so much is not because of their parameters being the mean and (sqrt of) variance. The most common reason is because of the fact that sums of random variables, pretty much regardless how they are distributed, limit to a normal distribution. This is called the central limit theorem.

On top of that, but many distributions might not be strictly gaussian but are generally bell-shaped and can be approximated by anything bell-shaped... including a gaussian. There are many probability distributions which are characterized by only a small number of parameters and the fact that those parameters are, for a gaussian, the mean and (sqrt of) variance, does not make it necessarily relevant for physical processes.

Comment: To the downvoter - if there is anything incorrect in my answer please let me know.